# Как поставить фокус на input при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Вообщем, хочу чтоб при нажатии на лупу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня открывался навбар и фокусилась форма для поиска [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, или дайте наводку, где черпать информацию.

Comment: сделайте триггер события фокус на инпуте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $('#input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">set focus</button>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```